# Javascript wont verify. jslint: Unexpected ']'

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have had this problem for a while now and I really don't know what to do. removing it creates more errors and I cant think of another alternative.

Here is a small section of code with most of it deleted but the error message still rings true.

javascript code:

```
var shapeCoords = [[-400, 0, 1, "#36648B"], [-400, 300, 2, "#36648B"], [400, 300, 2, "#36648B"], [400, 0, 3, "#36648B"],
                    ];

var imageState = false; //if true draw solid shape, if false draw line
var totalPoints = 532;

function drawPicture() {
    "use strict";
    var i;
    // draw viewport box
    clearGrid(true, true, 10);
    for (i = 0; i < totalPoints; i = i + 1) {
        drawShape(shapeCoords[i][0], shapeCoords[i][1], shapeCoords[i][2], imageState, shapeCoords[i][3]);
    }
}

function initialiseExample() {
    "use strict";
    drawPicture();
}

function toggleImageState() {
    "use strict";
    if (imageState === false) {
        imageState = true;
    } else {
        imageState = false;
    }
    drawPicture();
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please visit jsonlint.com to spot the exact error in similar situations.

Right now it is like this:

Correct:

```
var shapeCoords = [[-400, 0, 1, "#36648B"], [-400, 300, 2, "#36648B"], [400, 300, 2, "#36648B"], [400, 0, 3, "#36648B"]];
```

Wrong:

```
var shapeCoords = [[-400, 0, 1, "#36648B"], [-400, 300, 2, "#36648B"], [400, 300, 2, "#36648B"], [400, 0, 3, "#36648B"],];
```

Note the removed comma before the last closing square-bracket.

Comment: Thank you guys. I really don't understand how I could have overlooked that. I must have been having a moment. I would have ticked both of your answers but you can only tick one. Thank you once again.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Thank you for ticking my answer, but I suppose you can help @MikeSev by upvoting his answer!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the trailing `,` in your array, for example:

```
var shapeCoords = [[-400, 0, 1, "#36648B"], [-400, 300, 2, "#36648B"], [400, 300, 2, "#36648B"], [400, 0, 3, "#36648B"]];
```